# Error al instalar BeautifoulSoup mediante pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

Estoy tratando de instalar la librería BeautifulSoup con `pip` para Python 3.6:

```
$ pip install beautifulSoup
```

Pero me tira un error:

> ```
> (myvenv) eduardorr21@eduardoreyes21 ~/Documents/WebScraping $ pip 
> install beautifulSoup
> beautifulSoup
> Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/tmp/pip-install-9caehp9_/beautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
>     print "Unit tests have failed!"
>                                   ^
>   SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
>
> ----------------------------------------
>   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
> /tmp/pip-install-9caehp9_/beautifulSoup/
> ```

Supuestamente el archivo *setup.py* no esa actualizado y ya lo actualicé.

Answer (score 1):

Estas instalando el paquete equivocado. [`beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.1) se refiere a la rama **BeautifulSoup 3.x** en PyPi (como puedes ver en la traza del error), es un paquete marcado como **obsoleto** y solo compatible con Python 2 (de ahí el error con `print` en su *setup.py*). Se mantiene solo por retrocompatibilidad con código que en su día usó esta versión y no ha sido portado.

Debes instalar [BeautifulSoup 4.x](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). En la [documentación oficial](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) lo aclara muy bien:

> The BeautifulSoup package is probably not what you want. That’s the previous major release, Beautiful Soup 3. Lots of software uses BS3, so it’s still available, but if you’re writing new code you should install beautifulsoup4.

Por lo tanto debes hacer:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

---

No olvides luego importar de forma adecuada el paquete en tu script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```